# how to assign class object values to mutable array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the class object to store the xml parsed data. But now I need one mutable array and I want to store the class object values in new Mutable array.

Comment: Then What's your problem Now? Create an NSMutable array and add values to it.

Comment: What have you tried? : http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
[yourArray addObject:obj];
```